# Lost in translation - C# regex to JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having some trouble translating my working C# regular expression into JavaScript's regular expression implementation.

Here's the regular expression:

```
([a-z]+)((\d+)([a-z]+))?,?
```

When used on `"water2cups,flour4cups,salt2teaspoon"` you should get:

```
[
    ["water", "2cups", "2", "cups"]
    ["flout", "4cups", "4", "cups"]
    ["salt", "2teaspoon", "2", "teaspoon"]
]
```

... And it does. In C#. But not in JavaScript.

I know there are some minor differences across implementations. What am I missing to get this expression working in JavaScript?

**Update**

I am using the regex like so:

```
"water2cups,flour4cups,salt2teaspoon".match(/([a-z]+)((\d+)([a-z]+))?,?/g);
```

Comment: Re your update: If you use a `RegExp#exec` loop rather than `String#match`, you get the results you're expecting (see my answer). I'm not enough of a RegExp guru to tell you why. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Creating the RegExp

You haven't shown *how* you're creating your Javascript regular expression, e.g., are you using a literal:

```
var rex = /([a-z]+)((\d+)([a-z]+))?,?/;
```

or a string

```
var rex = new RegExp("([a-z]+)((\\d+)([a-z]+))?,?");
```

If the latter, note that I've escaped the backslash.

### Global Flag

By default, Javascript regular expressions are not global, that may be an issue for you. Add the `g` flag if you don't already have it:

```
var rex = /([a-z]+)((\d+)([a-z]+))?,?/g;
```

or

```
var rex = new RegExp("([a-z]+)((\\d+)([a-z]+))?,?", "g");
```

### Using `RegExp#exec` rather than `String#match`

Your edit says you're using `String#match` to get an array of matches. I have to admit I hardly ever use `String#match` (I use `RegExp#exec`, as below.) When I use `String#match` with your regex, I get...very odd results that vary from browser to browser. Using a `RegExp#exec` loop doesn't do that, so that's what I'd do.

### Working Example

This code does what you're looking for:

```
var rex, str, match, index;

rex = /([a-z]+)((\d+)([a-z]+))?,?/g;
str = "water2cups,flour4cups,salt2teaspoon";

rex.lastIndex = 0; // Workaround for bug/issue in some implementations (they cache literal regexes and don't reset the index for you)
while (match = rex.exec(str)) {
    log("Matched:");
    for (index = 0; index < match.length; ++index) {
        log("&nbsp;&nbsp;match[" + index + "]: |" + match[index] + "|");
    }
}
```

(The `log` function just appends text to a div.)

My output for that is:

```
Matched:
  match[0]: |water2cups,|
  match[1]: |water|
  match[2]: |2cups|
  match[3]: |2|
  match[4]: |cups|
Matched:
  match[0]: |flour4cups,|
  match[1]: |flour|
  match[2]: |4cups|
  match[3]: |4|
  match[4]: |cups|
Matched:
  match[0]: |salt2teaspoon|
  match[1]: |salt|
  match[2]: |2teaspoon|
  match[3]: |2|
  match[4]: |teaspoon|
```

(Recall that in Javascript, `match[0]` will be the *entire* match; then `match[1]` and so on are your capture groups.)

Answer (score 1):

C# had the "@" operator which automatically escapes backslashes ().
I do not think that Javascript supports it, so you basically need to "escape" the backslash by putting in another one, so this should do the trick

```
([a-z]+)((\d+)([a-z]+))?,?
```

Comment: You only have to escape backslashes if you're using a string to create the regex, not if you're using literal notation.