# Get all email addresses in a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

So, I have this JavaScript function:

```
ME.Utils = {
    RxEmail: new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i),

    ValidateEmail: function(email) {
        return ME.Utils.RxEmail.test(email);
    },

    GetEmailAddresses: function(text) {
        return text.match(ME.Utils.RxEmail);
    },

    HasEmail: function(text) {
        return ME.Utils.GetEmailAddresses != null;
    }
};
```

`ValidateEmail` works very well. However, `HasEmail` and `GetEmailAddresses` is not working properly.

`GetEmailAdresses` always returns `null`, except for when the string only contains an email address. In this case, `GetEmailAdresses` returns an array not only containing the email address, but the email address (test@test.com), just the id (test) plus some unidentified etc. etc...

Can you help me figure out what's wrong in my expression?

Comment: Oh look. Someone is trying to test email addresses with a regular expression. When was the last time I saw one that succeeded? Not today, it rejects email addresses with + characters in them.

Comment: Please stop mocking me. help me, or say nothing at all...

Comment: @david, it's a simple matter to add a + to the regexp. what is wrong with a decent regexp test for email?

Comment: @odeo, its not that simple.  see http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses and even that monster requires that some stripping is done first

Comment: There was a similar question on regexing email ids a couple of months ago, wasn't there?

Comment: Questions about parsing email addresses with regex cropup here on a regular basis, and they usually have false negatives on common address styles. I'm not mocking you, I'm expressing frustration at people failing to learn from history and making the same mistakes over and over again. Regular expressions are not suited to parsing email addresses in any depth but people insist on trying and failing again and again. Yahoo! is a huge company who's business is built about the web, and they can't get it right: http://twitter.com/edent/status/11687784947 - but so many smaller fish think they can.

Comment: @h2g2java: Try every few days: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=email%20[regex]&tab=newest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems.

1. Your regex is anchored at the start and end of the string. You should remove the `^` and `$` characters from it.
2. If you want to return only the email addresses, use non-capturing groups.
3. In `HasEmail()`, you're not calling `GetEmailAddresses()`. You're actually checking if the value of that property is defined.

All in all, a fixed version might look like:

```
ME.Utils = {
    RxEmail: /(?:(?:"[\w-\s]+")|(?:[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|(?:"[\w-\s]+")(?:[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(?:@(?:(?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.(?:[a-z]{2,6}(?:?:\.[a-z]{2})?))|(?:@\[?(?:(?:25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?)/gi,

    ValidateEmail: function(email) {
        // We can't do a simple test() since we're using an unanchored regex now.
        var match = ME.Utils.RxEmail.match(email);
        return match.length == 1 && match[0] == email;
    },

    GetEmailAddresses: function(text) {
        return text.match(ME.Utils.RxEmail);
    },

    HasEmail: function(text) {
        return ME.Utils.GetEmailAddresses(text) != null;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

your regexp specifically matches an entire string

```
RxEmail: new RegExp(/^ ... $)/i),
```

the ^ and $ match the start and end of the input respectively. try removing those characters and see how you get on?

Comment: thanks. apart from that your answer is more complete so +1 for you too buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (emailMatch = ME.Utils.GetEmailAddresses(myEmail))
  // do stuff with emailMatch[1]
```

Comment: not very helpful. I need to get an array with all email addresses in the string, like ["test@test.com", "sth@sth.com", etc@etc.com"]. Right now GetEmailAddresses returns an array full of junk.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting multiple entries in the array when presenting it with an email address is that you have capture groups in your expression. In Javascript, the result of match is an array where index 0 is the total string matched, and then there are (optionally) additional indexes for each capture group. You can make your groups non-capturing by changing them from `(...)` to `(?:...)`.

As for why you're not getting the results you expect when using `GetEmailAddresses` with a string *containing* an email address, try this instead:

```
GetEmailAddresses: function(text) {
    var rv = [];
    var match;

    while (match = ME.Utils.RxEmail.exec(text)) {
        rv.push(match[0]);
    }
    return rv.length == 0 ? null : rv;
},
```

See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772642/lost-in-translation-c-regex-to-javascript-regex/2772745#2772745), I can't say I know *why* `String#match` isn't quite the same as the `RegExp#exec` loop above, but it isn't.

**Edit** And you'll need to fix the issue that [oedo pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779465/get-all-email-addresses-in-a-string-with-javascript/2779518#2779518) as well; the RegExp needs to be allowed to match substrings.