# Shared regex (C# to JS) - Always false - what is wrong here?

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, email-validation

I want to use the same regex for server side as client side but when I convert it over to JS it always returns false. I think the string literal is causing the issue but I am not seeing where. I found this but still can't figure it out:
[Lost in translation - C# regex to JavaScript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772642/lost-in-translation-c-sharp-regex-to-javascript-regex)

Here is my server-side code:

```
public static string EmailRegex = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$";
```

Here is the razor:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" data-regex="@Model.EmailRegex" />
```

Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" data-regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$">
```

Here is the JS code which gets called on $("#email").keyup():

```
function validateElementRegex(element) {
    var regex = $(element).data("regex");
    var value = $(element).val();
    return validateRegex(value, regex);
}

function validateRegex(value, regex) {
    if (typeof(value) === "undefined" || typeof(regex) === "undefined") {
        return false;
    }
    var regexType = typeof(regex);        // string e.g. "^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$"
    var pattern = new RegExp(regex, "i"); // tried with and without "i" - ignoreCase
    var patternType = typeof(pattern);    // object
    var result = pattern.test(value);     // always false

    return result;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Waht is an example if what you are trying to match?

Comment: @MElliott 'test@gmail.com'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well you have an extra backslash in your regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

The above regex matches `email@myeamil\.com`

but it does not match `email@myeamil.com`

It should be:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```